# Adding periodic functions

Tags: periodic-functions

How to prove that sine is the only periodic function that retains its waveform when added to other sines with the same frequency (with an arbitrary phase and amplitude)?
 I read that Fourier used this property to develop his expansion method, therefore I’ve been searching for a proof which uses neither FT, nor eigenfunctions in general, as Fourier himself obviously couldn’t use that knowledge.